# CSS position of icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have little trouble with positioning an icon, could you please help me?
[Recent code]: http://bootply.com/112777
I am trying to position a ribbon icon at the left end of my line (I created the line by using `border-top` property on `li` element)
Thanks a lot!

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-7" id="top-banner">
       <ul>
         <li>
           <p class="sell1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> Ab nam amet enim aliquid veritatis eum! 
<i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#top-banner li {
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
    width: 320px;
}
.sell1 {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: where do you want the icon to be positioned?
I don't see any icon in your code

Comment: @tas9 You removed the CSS syntax highlighting.

Comment: I added the ribbon icon - for example the one that is included in the FontAwesome. The problem is that I have no idea how to take it out from the normal document flow and position it on the left end of <li> item border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to have the icon be to the left of the black line, you won't be able to do this to the using the top border of the li tag.

I added some html above your p tag, that will simulate an icon with a black line next to it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7S6zw/6/)

```
 <li>   
     <div class="icon_container">
          <div class="icon"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
     </div>
     <p class="sell1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> Ab nam amet enim aliquid veritatis eum! 
 </li>

.icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:thin solid black;
}
.line {
    width:280px;
    height:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:thin solid black;
}
#top-banner li {list-style: none; width: 320px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the closest to the effect I wanted. One more thing, do you know how to remove the pixel gap in between the p tag and the line? I tried margin: 0 but no luck. Because it is the ribbon, it should sort of lie directly next to the line - no gap.

Comment: The p tag by default has a margin on the top and bottom.  Try setting the margin-top on the p tag to 0px, which will bring it closer to the line.  You can even set the margin-top to -1px or more negative to pull the container upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I am only working on Guess work however assuming you want to add the icon before the first indented list-item you could use either of these options depending on your requirements:

**1)** Fixed a container in the top corner of your wrapping div.

```
#top-banner{    
  position:relative;
}
#top-banner:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:35px;
    background:#b00;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h67mP/

**2)** Simply set the background of the list item to top left and use padding.

```
.sell1 {
    background:url('Image.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h67mP/2/

**3)** Set the ALL list items to a background icon.

```
.col-lg-7 li{
  background:url('Image.png') no-repeat 0 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h67mP/3/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try absolute positioning a new `<div>` after `<div class="row">`

This method uses `position: absolute;` which will remove the element from the flow of the other elements. If this doesn't fit you could also `float` the surrounding elements or even use `display:inline-block;`. This can all depend on how you have your page setup.

**new html**

```
<div class="row"><div class="new"></div>
```

**new css**

```
.new {background-color:red;height:150px;width:25px;position:absolute;}
.row {position:relative;}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/4L54y/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your code like this. Please swap your awesome icon into the P tag so it comes on left of line.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-7" id="top-banner">
       <ul>
         <li>
           <p class="sell1"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> Ab nam amet enim aliquid veritatis eum! </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqrV9/)**

If you need it after your paragraph, make it like this.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-7" id="top-banner">
       <ul>
         <li>
           <p class="sell1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> 
           <p>Ab nam amet enim aliquid veritatis eum!</p>
           <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqrV9/1/)**